# Font Size on iPhone SMALLER than on PC

Tags: iphone, font-size

I've seen where the font size looks bigger on iPhone, but I am having the opposite problem. I am editing a very (very, very) old site for a client so that it can be viewed on a mobile phone. I have changed the font size on one particular page to be larger, but it still looks the same on the iPhone. I have tried inline styling, using !important, and pretty much anything else I can think of. It shows up larger on the PC, but not within mobile Safari.

The link to the page is http://smokingstinks-aaco.org/mobile/quiz.htm

Answer (score 0):

Is it that the font is smaller or is it because of the padding around the main content?
I would suggest using a fixed-width viewport meta tag to 700px which is your content width, this may help.

It's using tables to arrange the content which is a bit old school so maybe its worth re-doing the page anyway if you have time.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the option to re-code the whole site (at least at this moment). I have changed the font size on the home page (http://smokingstinks-aaco.org/mobile) and it worked just fine (see the description under the video feature). For some reason, this page isn't working the same way.